# How to do Volume Boost in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to find some information on how it's possible to boost the system volume above 100% - I know there are applications that can do it, but I'm not able to spot how they are able to do that. How can I do it programmatically, and which DLLs system calls are needed?

Comment: I doubt it can be done. VLC and others probably boost it in their own decoders.

Answer (score 1):

There is of course an upper limit on the system volume. Other software allows you to continue to zoom in after reaching the maximum volume, which is done at the time of decoding. You don't have a decoder.

There are actually two ways you can do something:

1. Directly amplify the waveform ----- this effect is limited
2. Write sound card driver, directly use the driver to modify the sound card output power.

The software never jumps out of the hardware limit. Increasing the volume will only make the sound quality worse.